# Unsigned int conversion C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out a serial program with C++. I'm sending a char array that consists of several uint8_t and several uint16_t that I'm trying to split up and send.

```
char buf[3];
uint16_t var=1500;
```

What's the difference (if any) between these:

```
buf[0]= var & 0xFF; buf[1]= var >> 8;
```

and

```
buf[0]= (uint8_t)(var & 0xFF); buf[1]= var >> 8;
```

The other end is expecting 16bit integers with LSB first and for some reason I just don't think I'm getting the expected serial write. I know there are a multitude of reasons this could be happening, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around the concept here.

Comment: What's the difference?  One of the lines contains a C-style cast to `uint8_t` and the other does not.  What question are you really asking here?

Comment: Does this "other end" perhaps use a different endianness than the sender?

Comment: I'm curious of why you're doing `var & 0xff`. Won't the implicit/explicit cast already truncate the most significant bits ?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of my question. I don't really understand the purpose if assigning to a char does the same thing.

Comment: I'm using some sample fragments I've collected from the MultiWii forums and GitHub. It's for a flight controller that has kind of so-so documentation on the serial protocol.

Comment: There's no difference between those two lines

Comment: My problem actually was a serial problem. Finally got the settings right. Flight controller is powering motors like a champ now.

Answer (score 1):

Most serial protocols want data in big-endian order.  In that case you should just do `*reinterpret_cast<short*>(buf) = htons(var)`.  If you really need little-endian, use `htole16`, defined in `string/endian.h`.